# how to make the price range for the configurable product in magento2 list page

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, layered-navigation

I want to  show the price as variation for example from 09 to 100 as this in magento2 in the list page

Comment: I have just done this by getting the special price and normal price of the product and make it as the variationable